# (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated\UXXXXXXXX escape

Tags: python

Пишу

```py
from PIL import Image
Img = Image.open('C:\Users\Asus\Dowloads\топ.jpg')
img.show()
```

Когда нажимаю Run Module пишет ошибку:

> (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated\UXXXXXXXX escape.

И выделяет красным в "img.show()" im

Comment: Попробуйте продублироват все символы \. Вот так: 'C:\\Users\\Asus\\Dowloads\\топ.jpg'

Comment: Если вы пишете код в PyCharm нажмите на File->Settings->Project: <project>-->Project Interpreter->+. Далее введите название модуля, который хотите установить (в вашем случае 'Pil') и нажмите на Install Package.

Comment: Все, спасибо, разобрался

Comment: Вам помог мой ответ, или вы разобрались с чем-то другим?

Comment: Помог ответ, и сам немного

Answer (score 2):

```
from PIL import Image
Img = Image.open(r'C:\Users\Asus\Dowloads\топ.jpg')
```

Попробуйте с r перед строкой или без русских символов в пути :)

Comment: Спасибо, помогли